# C++ preprocessor directive limits

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have a C++ pre-processor directive that is something like this:

```
#if (SOME_NUMBER != 999999999999999)
// do stuff
#endif
```

999999999999999 is obviously greater than 2<sup>32</sup>, so the value won't fit into a 32-bit integer. Will the preprocessor correctly use a 64-bit integer to resolve the comparison, or will it truncate one or both of the values?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: It certainly seemed to work, but I don't know if that was just because it truncated both of them down to INT32_MAX.

Comment: Another test with SOME_NUMBER equal to INT32_MAX will confirm whether that is happening or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the LL suffix:

```
#if (SOME_NUMBER != 999999999999999LL)
// do stuff
#endif
```

In my gcc this work fine:

```
#include <iostream>

#define SOME_NUMBER 999999999999999LL

int main()
{

#if (SOME_NUMBER != 999999999999999LL)
    std::cout << "yes\n";
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

With or without the LL suffix.

Comment: The suffix is unnecessary: "The type of an integer literal depends on its form, value, and suffix. If it is decimal and has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: …" (C++03 §2.13.1p2).

Comment: +1: Good. Yes I noticed that but I think is a good practice to specify explicitly the type.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `UINT_MAX` constant defined in "limits.h":

```
#if (SOME_NUMBER != UINT_MAX)
// do stuff
#endif
```

`UINT_MAX` value varies depending on the integer size.

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessor arithmetic works as normal constant expressions (see the Standard, 16.1/4), except that `int` and `unsigned int` are treated as if they were `long` and `unsigned long`.  Therefore, if you have a 64-bit type, you can use it as normal.